# How should I use Doxygen commands with an option as first argument?

Tags: doxygen

I have some trouble understanding some Doxygen command taking options as first argument (using HTML output).
Here, it is about the `\include` command but I believe that the answers (if any) will apply to other commands.

The [manual](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdinclude) says:

> You can add option {lineno} to enable line numbers for the included code if desired.
>
> You can add option {doc} to treat the file as documentation rather than code.

I can't get this to work.
This:

```
\include doc path/to/my/file
```

works fine. But the file content is considered as code (which is perfectly normal), and it actually holds some generated content that I want to be formatted as documentation.

I tried these (yeah, don't laugh, please):

```
\include doc path/to/my/file
\include [doc] path/to/my/file
\include {doc} path/to/my/file
\include {[doc]} path/to/my/file
\include [{doc}] path/to/my/file
```

but none of these works.
And its the same behavior with the `lineno` option.

To be complete, I have to mention that the manual gives some info about the notation [here](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html):

> Some commands have one or more arguments. Each argument has a certain range:
>
> If  braces are used the argument is a single word.
>
> If (round) braces are used the argument extends until the end of the line on which the command was found.
>
> If {curly} braces are used the argument extends until the next paragraph. Paragraphs are delimited by a blank line or by a section indicator.

But I don't understand how this relates to the above quote of the `\include` command manual.

Anybody has a clue ?

Doxygen version: 1.8.11 (Ubuntu 16.04 's latest).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First one has to distinguish between the different versions of doxygen. In the 1.8.11 version there are no options to e.g. the `\include` command, they are introduced in version 1.8.15.

The syntax for e.g. the `\include` command is in 1.8.15:

> \include[{lineno,doc}]

in the newer version this is written as:

> \include['{'option'}']

the rewrite was done because of it was not completely clear. Here (the new version, but this syntax is valid for 1.8.15 as well) the square brackets (`[` and `]`) signal the optionality the `'{'` and `'}'` signal that the curly brackets are mandatory. The option in this case can be either `lineno` or `doc`. furthermore you don't see a space between after `\include` and the curly bracket, this shouldn't be there, the curly brackets are part of the command. In case a space would be present it would be seen as the end of the command  and the `{` would be start of the argument.

In case of `\include` with say filename `xx.h` we can have:

`\include xx.h`

`\include{lineno} xx.h`

`\include{dox} xx.h`

This is about the options the other quote is about the arguments of a command.

Comment: Thanks. So this was just a version issue, glad to know about that. I did check the changelog, saw this: `Include command show line number (e.g. LaTeX)` but I thought it was only about LaTeX and line number.

Comment: ok, so I did miss the point that there must be no spaces. Anyway, just tried and I can confirm that this does not work with 1.8.11. I'll try to upgrade.

Comment: with 1.8.11 the command `\includelineno` is present and this does the same as `\include{lineno}`. The `\includedoc` was introduced in 1.8.12. The idea behind the options is to reduce the number of commands and keep the command list a bit more compact.

Comment: I just tried with a 1.8.15 binary, works fine... BUT no: actually my file content is a Markdown table, and it appears unformatted (if I paste it into my source, formatting is fine). I assume that Markdown processing occurs before the "include" process ? Anyway, this is a different issue, I might post an issue.

Comment: The markdown processing should be done correctly in 1.8.15 (by head), a new issue would be in place for it.

Comment: I found a solution: I changed the program generating the table: it now generates a raw html table that gets nicely formatted with `\include{doc}` (using 1.8.15)

Comment: To be honest I'm still interested in the markdown part to see what went wrong with the `\include{doc}` (you can post a new issue at https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/new and attach a, small, self contained example (source+configuration file in a tar or zip) that allows us to reproduce the problem.  Please don't add external links as they might not be persistent. Would also be nice to have the found solution in there (for comparison).

Comment: Okay, I'll try to do that, not until this WE.